# Index Error: Index 206893 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 206893, griddata issue

Tags: python, arrays, indexing, interpolation, bounds

I have an issue for the last 4 days trying to understand a python error:

```
`enter code here`IndexError: index 206893 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 206893
```

when applying, griddata and "nearest" interpolation method using the following lines:

## create a matrix where I will store the first interpolated file

```
tempnew    = np.ones((np.asarray(w1[0,0,:,:]).shape))*np.nan
```

## The lon, lat coordinate points of the original grid

```
lonl,latl  = np.meshgrid(lon,lat)
points     = np.vstack((np.array(lonl).flatten(),np.array(latl).flatten())).transpose()
```

## The values of the original file

```
values     = np.array([np.asarray(temp[0,0,:,:])]).flatten()
```

## The dimensions of the grid that I want to interpolate to

```
lons       = np.array(nav_lon)
lats       = np.array(nav_lat)
X,Y        = np.meshgrid(lons,lats)
```

## Interpolation

```
tempnew    = griddata(points,values, (X,Y), method = "nearest",fill_value=-3)
```

## Here the dimension of each of the variables that I use above:

```
 #tempnew.shape: (728, 312) #(Dimensions of tempnew is (lats,lons))

 #lat.shape: (661,) #(original latitude)

 #lon.shape: (313,) #(original longitude)

 #points.shape: (206893, 2)

 #values.shape: (206893,)

 #X.shape: (728, 312)

 #Y.shape: (728, 312)
```

Can you help me? * I would like to note here that the original file grid is regular (A-type) grid data whereas the grid to which I want to interpolate to is not regular (C-grid data)

The error looks like this:

```
In [36]: tempnew    = sp.interpolate.griddata(points,values, (X,Y), method = "nearest
...: ",fill_value=-3)                                                            
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-0d0b46a3542f> in <module>
----> 1 tempnew    = sp.interpolate.griddata(points,values, (X,Y), method = 
"nearest",fill_value=-3)

~/software/anaconda3/envs/mhw/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/ndgriddata.py in 
griddata(points, values, xi, method, fill_value, rescale)
217     elif method == 'nearest':
218         ip = NearestNDInterpolator(points, values, rescale=rescale)
--> 219         return ip(xi)
220     elif method == 'linear':
221         ip = LinearNDInterpolator(points, values, fill_value=fill_value,

~/software/anaconda3/envs/mhw/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/ndgriddata.py in 
__call__(self, *args)
 79         xi = self._scale_x(xi)
 80         dist, i = self.tree.query(xi)
 ---> 81         return self.values[i]
 82 
 83 

IndexError: index 206893 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 206893
```

Thanks in advance,
Sofi

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error in my Python code using the `scipy.interpolate.NearestNDInterpolator` class. The error message that is returned is not very clear. In the end, I found that one of the values I was inserting into my interpolant had a value of `1e184` and caused this error message. After resetting this value to `0.0`, my Python script ran successfully.